# Windows Phone Local database

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone, local-database

I want to built a data file based database for Windows Phone database and use it to store the following object of class.

```
public class employee()
{
   public int EmployeeNumber{get;set;}
   public string EmployeeFirstName{get;set;}
   public string EmployeeLastName{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What do you expect with above code ?

Comment: VTC: A simple search provides a detailed article on how to store data in a local relational database: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I want Sample CRUD operation on Above Model

Answer (score 0):

I think this Tutorial will Help you. 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18204.how-to-use-sqlite-with-a-windows-phone-8-application.aspx

Comment: An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in SqlLiteDemo.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: I follow the above link but getting this error please help and i am trying the sql lite connection from past 10 days and getting problem

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you may try to make a database with codefirst...
Codefirst is a new way to create database from code but you need to make a datacontext first.
See this example for windows phone 7 using sql ce https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Database-in-Windows-Phone-7-d69c13c9/sourcecode?fileId=65025&pathId=2036637683